# ReST API response codes

Tags: rest, api, response

I am trying to design a few ReST APIs.

One functionality is where for a request from the client to create a resource, the service should do 2 things

1. Create a resource on one system (s1)
2. Sync this data with another system (s2).

The client will then access s2 to read the data. A possible scenario is where the resource gets created on s1 but the sync to s2 fails.

Now, from the service's perspective the request was partially successful so a response code 207 with multistatus body may be okay to use but from client's perspective the resource is not yet available so this is a failure (status - 5xx).

Now which perspective should be considered while designing APIs?

Comment: After a successful data validation, The request is accepted(by s1) but more processing is pending(by s2), so a HTTP 202 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally implemented this is by making my processing asynchronous. As soon as the client sends the request, service persists the request, generates a new transaction id for this request and sends back a 202 response with a location header containing the url to query about the transaction status. It then attempts to process the request (create resource on s1 and sync it to s2) asynchronously. The client meanwhile can keep checking on the transaction status which will keep sending a "In progress" state. As soon as the request is processed, the transaction status is update to "success". On next query from the client, the success status is returned and then the client can move ahead.